# Page doesn't respond to user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I've just started using JavaScript and HTML, and one of my first assignments is to create a short trivia page. I was tasked with creating a multiple choice quiz, where the button turns green if that's the correct answer choice, and red if otherwise. For my question, the correct answer choice is 2. Nothing happens if I press a correct answer choice, or a wrong one.

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #212529;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #477bff;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #477bff;
    transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

button, input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #d9edff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="text"] {
    line-height: 1.8;
    width: 25%;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Trivia!</title>
            <script>
                // TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
                function check(id){
                    button = document.querySelector('#${id}')
                    if (id == '2') {
                        button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                    } else {
                        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    }
                }
                document.querySelector('#1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('1');
                });
                document.querySelector('#2').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('2');
                });
                document.querySelector('#3').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('3');
                });
                document.querySelector('#4').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('4');
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Trivia!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section">
                    <h2> Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                    <hr>
                    <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
                    <h3>
                        What does the Mushroom tell the other Mushroom when they're the only Mushrooms in their world?
                    </h3>
                    <button id="1"> I'm a Fun Guy!</button>
                    <button id="2">There's 2 mushroom?</button>
                    <button id="3"> Let me trufle over to you.</button>
                    <button id="4"> "Sigh". Lets wallop on the pizza-ria...</button>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to create a check function in JavaScript that evaluates the correctness based on the button number, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: There is a bunch I would do differently, But since you are new I would just move your javascript to the bottom of the page. The problem with having it in the head, is it is ran BEFORE the buttons are rendered in the DOM. Meaning when the javascript event handlers are created, the buttons technically don't exist yet.

Comment: After editing your question so that it can execute here inside of a Stack Snippet, you can run the code and see that you are getting an error. Always work with your browser's developer tools (F12) turned on and have the Console tab visible to see errors.

Comment: Also, please try to create a question title that corresponds to the problem you are having. Your current title is cryptic and has nothing to do with not seeing any results show up in your browser.

Comment: @Barmar By editing the question as you have, you have removed the part that shows where the problem is. The OP had his `script` located in the `head` section of the HTML page. After your edit, there's no way to know that and therefore no way for others to understand the issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Which is why I rolled back my edit.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, is it really "best practice" to answer questions in the comments? Aren't actual answer posts with their snippet features a better and more illustrative way of doing that?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann When the problem is due to a typo or a non-reproducible issue, yes. In those cases, we just comment as to the problem and vote to close the question.

Comment: In this case there hasn't been a typo and the error is reproducible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The core issue you're running into is that you are calling upon HTML elements which have yet to be created on your page. By moving your JavaScript lower, you're able to call upon your HTML elements properly.

Another one of the issues I see you're stumbling with is your id's being numbers. You can have numbers for id's, but using letters in your id will allow you to easily identify if you are working with a string or a number.

This allowed me to make a version of your code which is working (see the below code snippet).

```js
// TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
function check(id) {

  // Account for the id's now being strings starting with the word 'button'
  button = document.querySelector(`#button${id}`);
  
  if (id == '2') {
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  check('1');
});
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  check('2');
});
document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  check('3');
});
document.getElementById('button4').addEventListener('click', function() {
  check('4');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #212529;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #477bff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #477bff;
  transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}

button,
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #d9edff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="text"] {
  line-height: 1.8;
  width: 25%;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Trivia!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Trivia!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">
      <h2> Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
      <hr>
      <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
      <h3>
        What does the Mushroom tell the other Mushroom when they're the only Mushrooms in their world?
      </h3>
      <!-- Add letters into your id's, this way your id's won't be confused for numbers when they are strings -->
      <button id="button1"> I'm a Fun Guy!</button>
      <button id="button2">There's 2 mushroom?</button>
      <button id="button3"> Let me trufle over to you.</button>
      <button id="button4"> "Sigh". Lets wallop on the pizza-ria...</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
      <hr>
      <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add your JavaScript here instead -->
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The question has really already been answered in the comments. Your answer doesn't really add anything new. Also, numbers for `id`s don't contribute to this issue, so they are fine.

Comment: Scott, there's more than one issue the OP is facing and consolidating the issues into one answer should help clear things up. Like I stated in the answer, you CAN use numbers for an ID, but the OP isn't referencing them properly. An easy way to stop the errors the OP is getting is by using strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

To make your snippet work you would have to add a letter in front of your numeric ids, since otherwise you will run into CSS related problems when selecting them, see Scott Marcus's comment below and this page: https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #212529;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #477bff;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #477bff;
    transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

button, input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #d9edff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="text"] {
    line-height: 1.8;
    width: 25%;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Trivia!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Trivia!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section">
                    <h2> Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                    <hr>
                    <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
                    <h3>
                        What does the Mushroom tell the other Mushroom when they're the only Mushrooms in their world?
                    </h3>
                    <button id="a1"> I'm a Fun Guy!</button>
                    <button id="a2"> There's 2 mushroom?</button>
                    <button id="a3"> Let me truffle over to you.</button>
                    <button id="a4"> "Sigh". Lets wallop on the pizza-ria...</button>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script>
                // TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
                function check(id){
                    button = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
                    if (id == 'a2') {
                        button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                    } else {
                        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    }
                }
                document.querySelector('#a1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('a1');
                });
                document.querySelector('#a2').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('a2');
                });
                document.querySelector('#a3').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('a3');
                });
                document.querySelector('#a4').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    check('a4');
                });
            </script>
    </html>
```

Apart from that you should follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) rule and rewrite your code so there is only `.addEventListener()` assignment.

The

```
button=document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
```

assignment in your `check()` function can also be replaced by:

```
button=id
```

And in both cases it should be preceded by a `let` as you would otherwise pollute the global namespace.

Comment: In [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), the `id` attribute is allowed to be a number. That is not what the problem is. If you read the comments, you'll know that the issue is that the OP has the `script` element in the `head` section and therefore, the DOM references are undefined.

Comment: He's also running into the issue pointed out by Carsten too

Comment: When using an id like "1" I got this error: `'#1' is not a valid selector ...` so - at least here in the SO snippets a numeric id is not admissible.

Comment: That's because it's a problem with CSS, but your answer states that it's invalid in HTML.

Comment: Ok - (eating humble pie) - let us call it "problem with CSS" and not "invalid HTML". But in any case: it should not be done.